# ERROR - Nuget Package Manager: "is not a valid JSON object"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to configure a company intern NuGet, but I'm getting this error:

```
Error  [sourcename] Unable to load the service index for source [url].
The content at '[url]' is not a valid JSON object.
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Already checked my URL and my VPN is setting right

It looks like the package manager is expecting JSON, but the NuGet server is sending XML. How can I fix this?

Already change the URLs, and my colleagues can run normally

Answer (score 1):

Go to the NuGet Config via visual studio UI or by the follow path:

AppData/Roaming/Nuget/Nuget.config

Probably you will see a line there like `protocolVersion="3"` remove it or change to 2